# FirebaseAuthException ([firebase_auth/user-token-expired] The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.)

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I wrote a code like this:

```
  TextFormField(
    controller: _passwordController,
    obscureText: true,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
    ),
  ),
// ...
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.updatePassword(_passwordController.text).then((value) {
        }).catchError((e) {
          ModernAlert(
            context,
            "Hata",
            "Bir hata meydana geldi. Lütfen daha sonra tekrar deneyin.",
            "Tamam",
            () {},
          );
        });
```

My goal is to get new password from user with `TextFormField` and change his password in Firebase Auth system. But I am getting this error:

```
FirebaseAuthException ([firebase_auth/user-token-expired] The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.)
```

What could cause this problem? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error because user is **Unauthetication** , and read this doc [FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException)

Solve problem add this function:

```
Future<bool> _changePassword(String currentPassword, String newPassword) 
 async {
bool success = false;

//Create an instance of the current user.
var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
//Must re-authenticate user before updating the password. Otherwise it may 
fail or user get signed out.

final cred = await EmailAuthProvider.credential(email: user.email!, 
password: currentPassword);
await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(cred).then((value) async {
  await user.updatePassword(newPassword).then((_) {
    success = true;
  }).catchError((error) {
    print(error);
  });
}).catchError((err) {
  print(err);
});

   return success;
}
```

Comment: I can only access the user's current password from the login page. On the change information page, how can I get the current password of the user?

Comment: add new `TextFormField` for user current password and get `_passwordController.text` and change it , or if you like use otherway change password use Reset link password just input by user email and send from firebase smtp